# What's pyperclip's interaction with sudo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sudo, ubuntu-16.04, pyperclip

Info:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- python 3.5
- pyperclip 1.5.27

So I was trying to install `pyperclip` using `pip`; `pip install pyperclip` which failed with the error:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code -11 in /tmp/pip-build-########/pyperclip/
```

Looked it up, found error code 11 was mostly commonly caused because of some of a module being compiled in C? Not sure if that's right, but most people used:

```
sudo -H pip install pyperclip
```

Which worked fine for me, it installed. I then checked to see if it had gone through with:

```
python -c 'import pyperclip'
```

Which failed, with a 'module not found' error. After `pip freeze`, I tried to install it again (with `sudo`), but as it was already installed, that didn't work, so I tried `sudo -H pip install -U pyperclip`, which also didn't work because I had the latest version.

After scratching my head for a while, I tied `sudo -H pip freeze`. Suddenly, `pyperclip=1.5.27` was listed. It clicked around then. `sudo -H python -c 'import pyperclip'`... didn't work.

So now I'm really confused.

So clearly, something in `pip install pyperclip` needs `sudo`, despite being `python` being unable to run `pyperclip` with it. What's going on here? What can I do to work around it?

Slightly more information for a work around: I'm implementing a password script that just adds the desired password to the clipboard from a encrypted file on my computer, locked with a master password. Mostly for fun, but also so I can use a large number of passwords that all would take inhuman memory to know.